# Go through array of numbers but show result from position 2 Javascript JSX

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using an array of 51 positions, the same one that I traverse with map but I need it to be displayed only from position 2 to the end in order to avoid index 0 and 1 being displayed.

This is my code:

```
                      <select 
                        defaultValue={'DEFAULT'}
                          onChange={ (e) =>handlerPresentationSelected(e)}
                          className="border-solid border-2 border-slate-200 w-full p-2"
                          >
                          <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>Seleccione</option>
                          {  [...Array(51)].map( (value, index) => (
                              <option 
                                key={index} 
                                value={index}>
                                  { index }
                              </option>
                          ))}
                      </select>
```

How can I achieve it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<select
  defaultValue={"DEFAULT"}
  onChange={(e) => handlerPresentationSelected(e)}
  className="border-solid border-2 border-slate-200 w-full p-2"
>
  <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>
    Seleccione
  </option>
  {[...Array.from({length: 49}, (_, i) => i + 2)].map((value) => (
    <option key={value} value={value}>
      {value}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe build an array in a function with a loop, and then call that within the JSX instead.

```js
const { useState } = React;

function Example() {

  // Create an array from 2 to 51
  function getArray(n) {
    const arr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i <= n - 2; i++) {
      arr[i] = i + 2;
    }
    return arr;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <select>
        {getArray(51).map(n => {
          return <option value={n}>{n}</option>
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );

}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```